# JQuery - Recording time on mouse hover and on mouse rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to record times for two different JavaScript events. One for when the mouse isn't moving, and the other for when the mouse is moving.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeStart = new Date().getTime();
  var elapsedTime = (timeEnd - timeStart)/1000
});
```

I know of the JQuery event `mousemove` but am not sure how you would track time when a mouse is moving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var timer = null;
  var idleTime = 0;
  timer = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000);
  $(document).bind("mousemove", function (e) {
     idleTime = 0;
  });

  function timerIncrement() {
   idleTime = idleTime + 1;     
  }
});
```